# Unable to deploy Rails API app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk on Ruby 3.0 platform version 3.6.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

While trying to deploy in the "**Ruby 3.0 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.6.2**" platform, both using the `eb deploy` command or manually uploading a zipped version of my project, it seems the Postgresql service is not running in my instance since I get the next in `eb-engile.log`:

```
2023/01/17 17:31:04.238133 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [rake tasks]. Stop running the command. Error: running rake task db:migrate failed with error command bundle exec rake db:migrate failed with error Command /bin/su webapp -c bundle exec rake db:migrate failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:83:in `rescue in new_client'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:77:in `new_client'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `public_send'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `new_connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:926:in `checkout_new_connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:905:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:866:in `acquire_connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:588:in `checkout'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:428:in `connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1128:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:327:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:283:in `connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `initialize'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `new'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `connect'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:78:in `new_client'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `public_send'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `new_connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:926:in `checkout_new_connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:905:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:866:in `acquire_connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:588:in `checkout'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:428:in `connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1128:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:327:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:283:in `connection'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Although, when trying to run the `/bin/su webapp -c bundle exec rake db:migrate` command as root (please notice that, I am invoking bundler then as the webapp user), I get different kind of error (trying to install a missing gem?):

```rb
Bundler::PermissionError: There was an error while trying to write to
`/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/cache/public_suffix-5.0.1.gem`. It is likely that you
need to grant write permissions for that path.
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:105:in `rescue in
filesystem_access'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:102:in
`filesystem_access'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:479:in `block in
download_gem'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/retry.rb:40:in `run'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/retry.rb:30:in `attempt'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:470:in
`download_gem'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:485:in `download_gem'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:447:in `fetch_gem'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:431:in
`fetch_gem_if_possible'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:158:in `install'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
`install'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:155:in
`do_install'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:140:in
`install_serially'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:91:in
`call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:67:in
`call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer.rb:244:in
`install_in_parallel'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer.rb:201:in `install'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer.rb:89:in `block in run'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/process_lock.rb:19:in `rescue in lock'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/process_lock.rb:15:in `lock'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer.rb:71:in `run'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer.rb:23:in `install'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli/install.rb:62:in `run'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli.rb:260:in `block in install'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/settings.rb:131:in `temporary'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli.rb:259:in `install'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in
`run'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in
`invoke_command'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in
`dispatch'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli.rb:34:in `dispatch'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in
`start'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli.rb:28:in `start'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.1/exe/bundle:45:in `block in <top
(required)>'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in
`with_friendly_errors'
/opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.1/exe/bundle:33:in `<top
(required)>'
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'

An error occurred while installing public_suffix (5.0.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.

In Gemfile:
  capybara was resolved to 3.38.0, which depends on
    addressable was resolved to 2.8.1, which depends on
      public_suffix
```

It also seems the postgresql service is not installed (checked installed services starting with the "post" string):

```
[root@ip************ staging]# systemctl list-unit-files | grep post
postfix.service                               enabled
```

So, the question is, how do I make the `eb deploy` command run without failing? given that:

- I see one error using `eb deploy` that highlights a failing `rake db:migrate` command but, when trying to running it manually after connecting through SSH it throws a different error; the one that mentions `public_suffix`. This seems unexpected.
- The postgresql service should be installed in AWS's managed platform, as with previous versions

Comment: So what is the question? It appears you have determined that postgres is neither running or installed. This can be solved by installing postgres and running it.

Comment: In the context of using this AWS EB platform, postgres is supposed to be ready to go and not installed. That's one of the purposes of using EB: not having to install certain things manually because the managed platform and instances take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your app is trying to connect to a local database server:

```
Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

What are the contents of your `config/database.yml`? Is it reading environment variables that elasticbeanstalk knows to pass in? Does your RDS instance have the right access rules set up to allow connections from EB?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. To answer your points: 1. Yes 2. Yes 3. Yes. Actually all of this worked in a previous AWS platform but suddenly stopped working. I wasn't aware that my app is trying to connect locally (in which line did you notice that?), that is not my intention since I have an RDS instance set up. I would like to be more aware of what end point is being used and how to configure it.

Comment: I updated my answer to ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a database to your Elastic Beanstalk environment

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html